# Generating bar codes by enabling the Site Policy SharePoint feature or using third party websites

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, power-automate, powerapp, barcodes

I am working on an inventory app using SharePoint, Power Apps and Power Automate. And for the assets i want to generate bar codes that i can print and scan. now seems there are 2 approaches we can follow:-

1. Use 3rd party web sites which generate the bar code images
   2)Enable the related SharePoint site collection feature, so for each list item we will have a bar code, as follow:-

[image]

[image]

now i am not sure which approach to follow and why? in other word what are the advantages and disadvantages of each approach? considering that i am using Power Platform along with SharePoint online as the data source.

Thanks