# How I can remove the "BarCode" and "BaceCode Value" fields after disabling the Site Policy feature

Tags: sharepoint-online, barcodes

We want to generate barcodes for our SharePoint online list items and documents. so we enable the Site Policy Feature:-

[image]

and then we check the bar code checkbox:-

[image]

and we added the "BarCode" and "BaceCode Value" fields to the list view:-

[image]

Then we decide to use 3rpd party tool to generate the bar codes instead of SharePoint, as we will have more control on the bar codes format. so we disable the Site Policy feature + uncheck the barcode checkbox.. but the "BarCode" and "BaceCode Value" fields still show.. so how we can remove those fields on all the related lists and libraries?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can answer your own question about built-in barcode feature and third party tool as you seem to have made a choice. It will be good for the community to have your conclusion on this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/310520/generating-bar-codes-by-enabling-the-site-policy-sharepoint-feature-or-using-thi

Comment: @jleture i already mentioned why we went to 3rd party, is that they provide more barcode formats unlike SharePoint that only provide one format..

Comment: You should add this to your original question https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/310520/generating-bar-codes-by-enabling-the-site-policy-sharepoint-feature-or-using-thi not here

Comment: Even if you disable the feature, "BarCode" and "BaceCode Value" columns are still exist. You need to remove them from each view.