# BarCodes generated by SharePoint Vs Barcodes that come with the product for our Asset tracking system

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, barcodes

I am building an asset management system using SharePoint online inside Office 365. now some assets and spare parts come with barcodes stamp on them, while other do not. and in SharePoint when we create an item SharePoint automatically creates a barcode image and barcode value for each item as follow:-

[image]

now in addition to the Barcode & Barcode Value auto generated by SharePoint, I am storing a serial number.

now in our case when a spare part or asset leaves the store, we need to label it with a bar code, so when the technician want to replace the spare part, he can scan the bar code of the old spare part and the bar code of the new spare part and enter them inside the Maintenace work order/report.

but i am a bit confused on those points:-

1. is the Barcode value which is generated by SharePoint the same as the Serial number? and it does not make sense to have a Barcode value and a serial number as 2 separate fields as i am currently doing?
2. some spare parts will already have a barcode stamp on them when they come from the manufacturer. so how we need to enter those inside our system? as in this case the spare part will have 2 barcodes the one the comes with it from the manufacturer and the one the is generated from SharePoint.

I am really confused on how I need to store the bar codes and serial number for the assets and the spare parts. and do we need to generate them from SharePoint, or we only need to rely on the barcodes that comes already with the spare part and the assets?

Thanks

Comment: I thought you removed the built-in SharePoint barcode by a third-party solution? https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/310606/108220 It's very confusing to understand what your are doing!

Comment: Because you never help the community! It will be great if you share your expertise on the subject: when using the built-in feature of SharePoint and when using a third-party (from which vendor, at what cost, licensing, etc.). You ask many questions but never bring support to anyone.

Comment: @jleture this community have rules and regulations, and the admin decide if i am  breaking any of these.. and i do nto think so.. is it not this a place to ask questions or i am missing something?